# How to filter observable data not mutation source?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

There is events variable inside component:

```
 public readonly events$: Observable<IEvent[]>;
```

Data is coming from service:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
     this.events$ = this.eventService.get()
}
```

I wonder how to filter data not mutation initial `this.events$`?

**Filter by text field:**

```
public textChanged(text: string) {
}
```

**Filter by concrete field name:**

```
public filterByField(field: string, value: string) {
}
```

**Filter by date:**

```
public onDateChanged(date: Date) {
  
}
```

Do I think right that I need variable contains filtered data?

```
  public filteredEvents$: Observable<IEvent[]>;
  this.filteredEvents$ = this.events$; // Set initial data without filters
```

Then return mutated data in each method to this variable `this.filteredEvents$`?

will the data `this.events$` be changed after `this.filteredEvents$` changes? Because it has reference link `this.filteredEvents$ = this.events$;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that just using `pipe` and `filter`.

Filter by text field:

```
public textChanged(text: string) {
this.filteredEvents$ = this.events$.pipe(
  map(r => r.filter(q => q.textField === text))
 );
}
```

Filter by concrete field name:

```
public filterByField(field: string, value: any) {
this.filteredEvents$ = this.events$.pipe(
  map(r => r.filter(q => q[field] == value))
 );
}
```

Filter by date:

```
public onDateChanged(date: Date) {
 this.filteredEvents$ = this.events$.pipe(
   map(r => r.filter(q => q.dateField.getTime() == date.getTime()))
 );
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rkedu1-rxj-filter-data?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: When `this.filteredEvents$` is chnaged, has it effect to $events? Because it is refrence link

Comment: @Aurica nope it doesn't affect $events.

Comment: Why I have tested this: `let a = {id: 1}; let b = {id: 0}; a = b;  b.id = 100;` it has

Comment: Could you explain why it has no effect?

Comment: @Aurica `events$` variable just holds the source of the data. If you apply a pipable operation it doesn't modify the source it just processes the outcome. So if you subscribe `events$` observable somewhere else you will get the entire data there.

Comment: @Aurica added a stackblitz sample

Comment: you are wrong, $events has array so when you do: `this.filteredEvents$ = this.events$.pipe(
      filter((event: any) => {}` you get array in event, not element of array

Comment: @Aurica synced the answer with the stackblitz

Comment: Thank you, it works, one questiom what if date is null and I need reset filtered data to initial?

Comment: I made like this: ` r.filter((q) => {
          if (date)
            return (
              Helper.formatDateToISO(q.date) == Helper.formatDateToISO(date)
            );
          return q;
        })`

Comment: @Aurica you can use a trick like this : `r.filter(q => date == null || q.dateField.getTime() == date.getTime())`

Comment: @Aurica you can check the updated stackblitz. Click the nullifydate button and then filterbydate button.